# Xamarin.Forms Add NavigationBar

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to manage the nav bar appearence in the xaml?

And how can I manage the nav bar appearence in a Tabbed Page?
NavigationBar.SetHasNavigationBar(tabPage,true) seems not working.

Thank you all,

Ilenia

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check that your mainpage is wrapped with NavigationPage in the public App() function:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
```

Answer (score -1):

**Changing the color of your navigation bar**

To change the color of your navigation bar generically using `Xamarin.Forms` so that you only need to change the properties in one place, I'd suggest you add the following to your App.cs file like [mentioned in this post on the Xamarin Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/119859/#Comment_119859).

**Changing the color of the tab bar**

Unfortunately, changing the color of the `Tab Bar` is currently not supported in `xaml`.

You will although need to write a customer renderer for iOS like so:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace JetAdvice_Free.iOS.Renderers
{
    class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            TabBar.TintColor = MonoTouch.UIKit.UIColor.Black;
            TabBar.BarTintColor = MonoTouch.UIKit.UIColor.FromRGB(255, 128, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you use a `TappedPage` on iOS, the background color will be applied to your tab bar.

Comment: While this is true, it does not address the posters issue: "NavigationBar.SetHasNavigationBar(tabPage,true) seems not working."

Answer (score -1):

You can set the navigationbar color only when you initialize your navigationpage like so:

```
new NavigationPage(your page here)
        {
            BarBackgroundColor = Color.Green,
            BarTextColor = Color.White
        };
```

For the issue of setting the tintcolor of the tabbar I recommend using a renderer like so:

```
public class TabPage_iOS : TabbedRenderer
{
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        this.TabBar.TintColor = Color.Blue.ToUIColor();

        UITableView tableView = (UITableView)this.MoreNavigationController.TopViewController.View;
        tableView.TintColor = this.TabBar.TintColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is true, it does not address the posters issue: "NavigationBar.SetHasNavigationBar(tabPage,true) seems not working."